# BotFramework Avoid Confirmation in FormFlow

Tags: botframework, formflow

I want to bypass the last confirmation step in a formflow which is defined like this

```
new FormBuilder<WizardResult>()
                .Confirm("No verification will be shown", state => false)
                .Message("Form Test")
                .OnCompletion(processOrder)
                .Build();
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007500/skip-confirmation-step-with-microsoftbots-formbuilder)  this could be done with the handler in confirm, but in my case the confirmation is still asked...

what am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

It version 3.3.1.0 you only need to call

```
.AddRemainingFields()
```

in the FormBuilder to avoid the confirmation. The state=> false is not required any more.